# ASP.NET Page.User is null during AJAX request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, yui3

I'm using the MVC2 framework and one of my views has a bit of conditional logic that gets the Page.User.Identity object and does a comparison with other values to determine what to display.

That all works fine on the initial page load, but when I make an AJAX call to get partial page updates (I'm doing this all manually with YUI3, not the .NET AJAX stuff) the Page.User object is always null.

Anyone know why the Page context seems to be discarding the User object for asynchronous requests?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

If your request-handling method is a static `WebMethod`, there won't be a page instance to work with and `Page` itself will be `null` (that is, you won't even be able to resolve `Page.User`).

If that is indeed the problem, use `HttpContext.Current.User` instead. (And be sure to read [Why do ASP.NET AJAX page methods have to be static?](http://encosia.com/2008/04/16/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/))